# Python in-place merge sort error: index out of range

Tags: python, mergesort

would anyone know why my in place merge sort is **"index out of range"**?

I originally had my "low" at 0 but decided to do a +1 for each "low,mid,high" to compensate for index space. Can anyone find anything? Thanks.

```
def merge(array, low, mid, high):

    i,j,k = low,mid+1,low
    leftarray = array[low:mid+1]
    rightarray = array[mid+1:high+1]

    temp= [0]*high

    while i<=mid and j<=high:

        if array[i]<array[j]:
            temp[k] = array[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            temp[k] = array[j]
            j+=1
        k+=1

    if i>mid:
        temp[k:high+1] = array[j:high+1]
    else:
        temp[k:high+1] = array[i:mid+1]  

    array[low:high+1] = temp[low:high+1]

    def inplace(array,low,high):

        if low<high:
            mid = int((low+high)/2)
            inplace(array,low,mid)
            inplace(array,mid+1,high)
            merge_test(array,low,mid,high)


    array = [20,30,21,15,42,45,31,0,9]
    inplace(array, 0, len(array)-1)
    print(array)
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is. Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The error you have is in your code this part is incorrectly indented. It should be outside of while loop. Once merging is done. **Refer to merge sort pseudo code to find where is the bug.**

```
if i>mid:
    temp[k:high+1] = array[j:high+1]
else:
    temp[k:high+1] = array[i:mid+1]  

array[low:high+1] = temp[low:high+1]
```

- The following code is working.

```
def merge_test(array, low, mid, high):

    i,j,k = low,mid+1,low
    leftarray = array[low:mid+1]
    rightarray = array[mid+1:high+1]

    temp= [0]*high

    while i<=mid and j<=high:

        if array[i]<array[j]:
            temp[k] = array[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            temp[k] = array[j]
            j+=1
        k+=1


    if i>mid:
        temp[k:high+1] = array[j:high+1]
    else:
        temp[k:high+1] = array[i:mid+1]  

    array[low:high+1] = temp[low:high+1]


def inplace(array,low,high):

    if low<high:
        mid = int((low+high)/2)
        inplace(array,low,mid)
        inplace(array,mid+1,high)
        merge_test(array,low,mid,high)


array = [20,30,21,15,42,45,31,0,9]
inplace(array, 0, len(array)-1)
print(array)
```

**output**:

```
[0, 9, 15, 20, 21, 30, 31, 42, 45]
```

**PS: please always post full error stack trace. It helps debugging code. You should also try reading stack trace.**